# Check boxlist selection from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have Checkbox list and selection list also from database

i can fill checkboxlist from db in below

i have one datatable for selection items

i want that values to be selected in this checklist.

dt pagelist contains 1 to 10

dt checklist contains 1,3,5,7

```
  DataTable dt = obj.checklist();
  public void pagelist() 


{
    DataTable pl = obj.pagelist();
     foreach (DataRow row in pl.Rows)
    {
        ListItem item = new ListItem();
        item.Text = row["Previlage_pageName"].ToString();
        item.Value = row["Previliges_ID"].ToString();
        CHpagelist.Items.Add(item);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think this should work

```
            ListItem item = new ListItem();
            item.Text = row["Previlage_pageName"].ToString();
            item.Value = row["Previliges_ID"].ToString();
            item.Selected = true;
            CHpagelist.Items.Add(item);
```